# Python Plotly RangeSelector for data

Tags: python, plotly

I'm using Plotly in my python script in order to display data.

Is there **a range selector on plotly** to display only some of data? I have too many data to display so I want to use range selector to display some of them.

Or at least I would like to **appendleft or appendright data whenever I click the button**.

Comment: What kind of data would you like to display? Time series?

Answer (score 0):

If it's time seriers you'd like to display, plotly has got a pretty cool range selector that's described [here](https://plot.ly/python/range-slider/).

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

# Load data
df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")
df.columns = [col.replace("AAPL.", "") for col in df.columns]

# Create figure
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date), y=list(df.High)))

# Set title
fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Time series with range slider and selectors"
)

# Add range slider
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=go.layout.XAxis(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=6,
                     label="6m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="YTD",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="todate"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1y",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    )
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Actually, I already tried that solution. It turned out that there were too many time series data on my file and it was impossible to display all of them ( it simply stops ).
So I want to display the time series data by entering from data to data or with buttons.

Comment: So the bottom range selector doesn't work for me, the top buttons are solutions but they don't take any specific period input(from and to).

Comment: There are other ways to fix this, but I'll need a better understanding of your data. A limited data sample would be nice.

Comment: Sorry for being late, let me make and give you another comment within a couple of days.